# How to access values of a jobject in JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

```
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_ramRead_MainClass_readRam
        (JNIEnv *env, jobject, jobject len, jobject addr, jint pid)
{
        jclass c = (*env).GetObjectClass(len);
        jfieldID fid = (*env).GetFieldID(c, "len", "Ljava/math/BigInteger;");
        std::cout << "Object Field: " << (*env).GetObjectField(len, fid);

        struct iovec local[1];
        struct iovec remote[1];
        unsigned long long len1 = (*env).GetObjectField(len, fid) //This did not work out. the conversion to unsigned long long
        jbyte buf[len];
        jbyteArray buf1 = (*env).NewByteArray(len);

        local[0].iov_base = buf;
        local[0].iov_len = len;

        remote[0].iov_base = (void *) addr;
        remote[0].iov_len = len;

        nread = process_vm_readv(pid, local, 1, remote, 1, 0);

        (*env).SetByteArrayRegion(buf1, 0, len, buf);
        return buf1;
}
```

This is my native method and as you can see, it receives 3 parameters as arguments two `jobject` and one `int`. The two jobjects are big integers,
Originally it revived as parameters two `int` and one `long` but as I need to pass big integers now I have a problem or should I say several of them.

Goal:

I need to get the `BigInteger` value from `jobject len` and then I need to use it to initialize the size of `jbyte buf[len]` , `jbyteArray buf1 = (*env).NewByteArray(len)` and `local[0].iov_len = len;` I cannot of course just initialize them with `len` I need to get the big integer value from `len` and then initialize the size with that. 
And then I need to do the same, with jobject addr that is extract the big integer value from it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see the point of using a `BigInteger` here if you're converting it to a `unsigned long long` any ways. Why not just pass a Java `long`?

Comment: Well I tried converting to long long but it did not work. Why a BigInteger? Well the number is really big, to give you an example this is one of the numbers in hex: ffffffffff601000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that you're trying to access a field of `BigInteger` call `len`:

```
GetFieldID(c, "len", "Ljava/math/BigInteger;");
```

But `BigInteger` doesn't have such a field.

There is no way to access the "value" of a `BigInteger` directly. The best you can do from JNI is convert the `BigInteger` to a `jlong` (by calling the Java method `longValue`, on the `BigInteger`) and use that.

But, there is no point in using a `BigInteger` if you're converting it to an `jlong` any ways. You would lose any precision you'd gain from using a `BigInteger`. So might as well use a `long` in Java instead (which will still fit the value `0xffffffffff601000` that you mentioned).

Furthermore, a `byte[]` can only be indexed with an `int`, so even if you make `buf` bigger than that, it won't be accessible from Java.

I would recommand using a direct `ByteBuffer` instead of a `byte[]`, since you won't have to copy data across buffers.

You'd get something like this:

```
private static native void readRam(ByteBuffer buff, long address, int pid);
```

And then in C++:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Main_readRam
    (JNIEnv *env, jclass, jobject byteBuffer, jlong addr jint pid) {

    struct iovec local[1];
    struct iovec remote[1];

    void* buf = env->GetDirectBufferAddress(byteBuffer);
    jlong len = env->GetDirectBufferCapacity(byteBuffer);

    local[0].iov_base = buf;
    local[0].iov_len = len;

    remote[0].iov_base = (void *) addr;
    remote[0].iov_len = len;

    process_vm_readv(pid, local, 1, remote, 1, 0);
}
```

And then calling:

```
int bufferLength = ...;
long address = 0xffffffffff601000L;
int pid = ...;

ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(bufferLength);

readRam(bb, address, pid);

// use bb...
```

---

In regards to your comment, you could do this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while(bb.hasRemaining()) {
    byte b = bb.get();
    if((b >= 32 && b < 127) || b == 10) {
        sb.append((char) b);
    }
}
String result = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I did previously try something similar with a byte array as well and it worked but I thought I needed big integers and then it got messy. The problem is now when I try to read the ByteBuffer with bb.hasRemaining() and bb.get() I get BufferUnderflowException I ve read in the documentation what it is but cannot seam to get around it. Further more I need to interpret the elements of this bytebuffer as chars and store them into a string. This is what I did with the byte[] array

Comment: byte[] x = this.readRam(readSize, addr, PID);
  String s = "";
  for(int i=0; i<x.length; i++)
  { 
   if(((int)x[i] >= 32 && (int)x[i] < 127) || (int)x[i]==10)
   {
    s = s+(char)x[i];
   }
  }
  return s;

Comment: Thank you so much it works like a charm I just wish I had more rep so I could at the very least up vote your answer.